# Derailleur broken?

Tags: derailleur-rear

I had a crash recently and now I have taken off my rear mech and seen that the guide pulley is spinning as usual but the tension pulley is getting stuck.
There is a picture below of the broken pulley.
Is it fixable or do I need a new rear mech?
Thanks
[image]

Comment: Am I missing something obvious or does it look fine in the photo? (as far as it’s possible to tell). If you are sure that only the pulley wheel (or its bearing) is damaged you can get new pulley wheels. Or ask your local bike shop or repair café they often have used ones lying around.

Comment: There's no chain, so both pulleys should spin without significant resistance.  Do they?   Could be the cage is slightly tweaked to the left, but could also be angles or the camera lens.   You should absolutely try to fix it before buying a replacement.

Comment: I don't see anything obviously wrong. Replacement pulleys are cheap enough in any case.

Comment: Is there material interfering with the lower, tension pulley to prevent it from turning?

Comment: It's possible that the cage has been bent.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the picture there is nothing that prevents the pulley from spinning.

It's worth the small amount of work needed to remove the pulley on the chance that it can be fixed before getting a new derailleur.

Once removed from the cage look for dirt, bent parts or other obstructions. It may take a little experimenting to find the problem.